# How can I convert this into a integer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I asked a similar question yesterday .. If I have for example 0-9999 , how can I turn this into 09999 , basically removing the - and make it an integer in javascript ?

var = 0-9999

turn that into 9999 integer

or var  = 2-9999 , turn that into 29999

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Do you have it as strings? I mean, `var x = "2-9999"`? Because `var x = 2-9999` is `-9997`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = '0-9999';
var int = Number(i.replace('-', ''));
window.alert(int);
```

Note in Firefox, `parseInt()` won't work with leading zeros unless you pass in a radix (this appears to be a bug):

```
var int = parseInt(i.replace('-', ''), 10);
```

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/XUUxH/)

Comment: There is a bug report indeed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=510415

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
num = num.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '') * 1;
```

It'll strip out any non-numeric characters and convert the variable into an integer. Here's a [jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ynu9z/) for you.

Comment: Shorter: `num = +num.replace(/\D/g, '')`

Comment: @gilly3: Clever. :) I like the `+num` method, but `*1` was the first that came to mind.

Comment: @gilly3 I think you give up too much readability, though I like the shorter regex. It's more obvious IMO what `* 1` is doing vs `+` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious and basic of solutions would be:

```
var s = "1-2345";
var t = s.replace("-","");
var i = parseInt(t,10);
```

But that's making a lot of assumptions and ignoring any errors.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville He's only supplied dashes, but you are right. Like your solution, +1!

Comment: `parseInt` will convert `09999` into `0`.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Really? Not 9999?

Comment: Don't forget your radix. :)

Comment: It depends on the browser, but older ones will assume base 8 and return `NaN` or `0` for `09999`. The safe route is `parseInt(t, 10)`.

Comment: @Lloyd - Yea [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/c5xRn/) - Though I've only tried it on Firefox.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Oh good catch, `parseInt('0999', 10)` *will* return 999.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Interesting I didn't know that :/

Comment: @MikeChristensen Argh, Firefox is not following ES5: "If radix is undefined or 0, it is assumed to be 10 except when the number begins with the character pairs 0x or 0X". I'd expect that from old IE, but not FF...

Comment: @Lloyd - Neither did I, until about 5 minutes ago!

Comment: Ah reported in 2009, guess we shouldn't hold our breath.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that

```
var x = 2-9999
```

is the same as

```
var x = -9997
```

because the dash is seen as a subtraction symbol unless you use quotation marks (Single or double, doesn't matter).

So, assuming that you properly quote the text, you can use the following function to always pull out a character that is in any given spot of the text (Using a zero-based index).

```
function extractChar(myString,locationOfChar){
    var y = myString.substring(0,locationOfChar-1)
    var z = myString.substring(locationOfChar+1)
    var s = y.concat(z)
    var i = parseInt(s,10)
    return i 
}
```

therefore

```
var i = extractChar("2-9999",1)
```

Will be the same as

```
var i = 29999
```