# Javascript code to convert serial numbers converted from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, javascript-framework

These two Javascript functions are supposed to convert serial numbers (2-9999) for example into a number , but the functions below are not working for some reason .. they were originally written in PHP ... Works in PHP but not for Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function my_isnum(str, negative=false, decimal=false)
{
    var has_decimal = false;
    var len = strlen(str);
    if (len > 0) {
        var valid = true;
        for (var i=0; valid && i < len; i++) {
            if (!(str[i] >= "0" && str[i] <= "9")) {
                if (str[i] == "-") {
                    if (!negative || i != 0) {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                } else if (str[i] == ".") {
                    if (!decimal || has_decimal) {
                        valid = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

function esn_to_num(esn) {
    var tmp = [];
    if ((tmp = esn.split("-")) {
        if (tmp.length == 2
            && my_isnum(tmp[0])
            && my_isnum(tmp[1])
        ) {
            esn = ((tmp[0] << 23) | tmp[1]);
        } else {
            esn = -1;
        }
    } else {
        esn = -1;
    }
    return esn;
}

alert(2-9999);

</script> </head>
</html>
```

Original PHP functions

```
<?php
function my_isnum($str, $negative=false, $decimal=false)
{
    $has_decimal = false;
    $len = strlen($str);
    if ($len > 0) {
        $valid = true;
        for ($i=0; $valid && $i<$len; $i++) {
            if (!($str[$i] >= '0' && $str[$i] <= '9')) {
                if ($str[$i] == '-') {
                    if (!$negative || $i != 0) {
                        $valid = false;
                    }
                } else if ($str[$i] == '.') {
                    if (!$decimal || $has_decimal) {
                        $valid = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $valid = false;
    }
    return $valid;
}

function esn_to_num($esn)
{

    if (($tmp = explode('-', $esn))) {

        if (sizeof($tmp) == 2
            && my_isnum($tmp[0])
            && my_isnum($tmp[1])
        ) {
            $esn = (($tmp[0] << 23) | $tmp[1]);
        } else {
            $esn = -1;
        }
    } else {
        $esn = -1;
    }

    return $esn;
}




?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like ParseFloat ?

Comment: Didn't you like the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656412/how-can-i-convert-this-short-php-function-into-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654753/how-can-i-convert-this-into-a-integer-in-javascript)?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as `strlen` in Javascript. Use `str.length` instead.

Also, as Jason Sperske suggested below, change this:

```
function my_isnum(str, negative=false, decimal=false)
```

To this:

```
function my_isnum(str, negative, decimal)
{
    if (typeof negative == "undefined") negative = false;
    if (typeof decimal == "undefined") decimal = false;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Also, `function my_isnum(str, negative=false decimal=false)` is not valid JavaScript

Comment: Yeah I was looking at that after I posted the answer, but indeed! (For anyone who doesn't see it: missing comma between `false` and `decimal` )

Comment: Sorry the mistake is larger than that, functions in JavaScript don't have default values like that

Comment: I KNEW IT! I didn't know for sure, so I looked it up, and the first page I opened said it did... Stupid me for not looking further than that. Internet mistake #1...

Comment: Wait wait wait... http://jsfiddle.net/M9KTN/ JabaScript is currently blowing my mind, what am I not understanding here?

Comment: In Chrome: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = `

Comment: That seems more like normal, but in Firefox?

Comment: Yeah... It's weird... Also I updated your suggestion in my answer, because what I was doing there was just... wrong... Haven't done an excessive amount of JS in a while.

Comment: As it happens, you only use `negative` and `decimal` in a boolean manner defaulting to false, so it doesn't matter if you leave them undefined or not.

Comment: I know, but I tried to give a more general and reusable answer ;-)

Comment: Turns out the [default arguments thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657117/do-function-argements-support-a-default-value-in-javascript) is FireFox supporting something before anyone else

Comment: @JasonSperske: That explains it!

Comment: @JBa: Can you post your code (after my changes) on JSfiddle and post the link in the question, please?

Answer (score 3):

> These two javascript functions are supposed to convert serial numbers (2-9999) for example into a number.

Why not just get rid of the `-` and parse as a decimal number?

```
function padToFourDigits(_, digits) {
  return "0000".substring(digits.length) + digits;
}

function serialToNum(serialNumStr) {
  return +(serialNumStr.replace(/-(\d{1,4})/g, padToFourDigits));
}
```

Then

```
serialToNum('2-9999') === 29999

serialToNum('2-999')  === 20999
```

Comment: Yes, the OP got this advice [earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654753/how-can-i-convert-this-into-a-integer-in-javascript), but for some reason decided not to take it.

Comment: @Mike .. It's an assignment .. I wish I could just do it like that

Comment: @JBa Did the assignment tell you to do a line for line port of the code or just implement the same functionality in javascript? Personally if I had giving this assignment and you returned with the answer above I would think very highly of it, as you would have greatly simplified the code.